# QDialog show() follow with return result actions

Tags: c++, qt

I created a login GUI using QDialog, which has a slot `bool Login::on_OKbutton_Clicked()` that returns the login sucessful status `public: bool loginsucessful`, and after that I want to do some judgements based on that result, the code looks like this:

```
//Login class
Login::Login(QString Ver, QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Login)
{
 public:
     bool loginsucessful = 0;
     bool on_OKbutton_Clicked()
         {
              // login data acquisition and verification
              if (verification_passed) { loginsucessful = 1};
         }

//outer codes
Login *login = new Login(ver);
login->show();
//here is the question
if (login.loginsucessful)
    {...}
else {...}
```

I want the `if` folloeups execute after the Login GUI been finished(OK or Cancel button clicked), but the `.show()` won't do, I tried `.exec()` but will conflict with out codes like `(QApplication) a.exec()` causing un-terminated process problems.

I just starting programming with Qt, so is there good solution that waits the GUI and excute following codes after it being closed? Great thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `login->exec()` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a blocking way to show the dialog and access the results you can use `exec()` and see the results when it returns :

```
login = new Login();
if(login->exec())
{
    bool result = login->loginsucessful;
    if (result)
    {
       ...
    }
    else 
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I am a rookie and I think this question should be silly. How do I exit the loop after `login->exec()`? I used `app.exec` in main.cpp which includes a `login->exec()` loop inside, the app cant seem to terminate when I hit the button

Comment: `exec()` shows the dialog as a modal dialog and blocks until the user closes it. So when the dialog is closed in any way, the loop is exited.